# Available URI for Intent ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent

I am exploring ACTION_PICK intent in android.

According to docs:

> Input: getData() is URI containing a directory of data (vnd.android.cursor.dir/*) from which to pick an item.

For now I only know 4 built in URI that can be used in ACTION_PICK:

1. MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI (for images)
2. MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI (for audios)
3. MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI (for videos)
4. ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI (for contacts)

Although we can pass our own URI but ***I would like to know the complete list of URIs that are provided by android.***

PS: Is there any default URI for text files like pdf docs etc?

Comment: @pskink Many reasons, I would like to know what URIs can I use to start an intent. Like mentioned in the question, I would like to know if there is any URI for text files, or URI for pdfs only and more. So if I can have a look at all the URIs that are available It would be very easy to start intent for that specific URI.

Comment: I have referred docs, they say that ACTION_PICK requires a URI. 
@pskink So if I use a URI for contacts and mimetype of image would it work? So you are saying that the input is optional?

Comment: @pskink URI also does one more thing. While MIME type specifies the type of data to return, it won't restrict the type of data visible in the file explorer. URI on the other hand, would restrict the application to show only specific type of data.

Comment: @pskink, If I were to use mimetype only, it wouldn't work, I don't explicitly remember but something like, no application to view this type of data.

Comment: @pskink Try using intent.setType("application/*"); It wouldn't give you any app to select.

Comment: I used application/*  I can also try with application/pdf, if you want!

Comment: @pskink I used this: intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("application/pdf"); 
And it opened a popup, **No apps can perform this action.**

Comment: @pskink output is long so trimming some of it
 application/pdf:
        c2ae874 com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.PdfViewerActivity
        e0a76b2 com.android.bluetooth/.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity
      application/sdp:
        ca9f062 com.google.android.apps.photos/.pager.HostPhotoPagerActivity
      application/zip:
        e0a76b2 com.android.bluetooth/.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity
      text/html:
        6c5a06b com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity

Comment: It is giving me nonstatic method cannot be referenced no matter where I add this code!

Comment: @pskink It returns an empty list! This is what I wrote: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

Comment: Yes, For now I want to open an intent that would only show pdf, docs, text files to select. i.e. all files with this mimetype "application/*"  **No images No audios No videos.**

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I was first using ACTION_GET_CONTENT only, but the thing is it won't restrict file browser to show a specific type of mime types. More specifically, it allowed me to choose audios and videos when i set the mime type to "image/*"

Comment: Any ideas for this? Also, I ran into one more problem. I was using ACTION_PICK, for mimetype of audio in my device(android M 6.0.1) and the app crashed saying no activity found to handle this intent. The error message itself is clear so I guess I cannot use ACTION_PICK anymore. So how do I go on filtering data based on mimetype? Any help would be appreciated. @Commonsware